# Updating a 3D graph every n minutes in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code to plot a 3D graph in Python

```
data = # taken from an SQL query in (x, y, z) format #

x, y, z = zip(*data)
z = map(float, z)
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):100j, min(y):max(y):100j]
grid_z = griddata((x, y), z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
plt.show()
```

I want the plot to be undated every 1 minute. I can get the data from the table using a thread every 1 minute but I am unable to update the plot.

Can you help me with a suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a way of doing this with matplotlib.animation.

The below Youtube link was of great help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w8jk0r4lxA

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while True:
    plt.pause(1)
    x1,x2,x3=random.uniform(-10,0),random.uniform(0,10),random.uniform(0,0.5)
    y1,y2,y3=random.uniform(-10,0),random.uniform(0,10),random.uniform(0,0.5)

    X,Y=np.arange(x1,x2,x3),np.arange(y1,y2,y3)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    Z = np.sin(R)
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

    plt.draw()
```

[matplotlib.pyplot.pause](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pause#matplotlib.pyplot.pause)

```
Pause for interval seconds.
If there is an active figure it will be updated and displayed, and the GUI event loop will run during the pause.
If there is no active figure, or if a non-interactive backend is in use, this executes time.sleep(interval).
This can be used for crude animation. For more complex animation, see matplotlib.animation.
This function is experimental; its behavior may be changed or extended in a future release.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will try this and see if it works.

Comment: I tried this solution and it doesn't work :( The graph doesn't get updated. If I close the graph GUI then the graph gets drawn after the interval. But if not it doesn't get updated.